# UISearchBar in UIView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6

I'm having difficulty following directions.  I have a UISearchBar in a UIView.  The user will enter the search string into the UISearchBar and click the search icon to search.  The results will display in a new window (UITableView).

My search has shown me this:

> A UISearchDisplayController cannot be added to a UIView because it
>   doesn't inherit from a UIView. You can add a UISearchBar in Interface
>   builder with an IBOutlet and then create a UISearchDisplayController
>   with that UISearchBar programmatically.
>
> Just do it in code e.g. (assuming the view controller is vc): [vc
>   addSubview:mySearchDisplayController.searchBar]; // Note that
>   searchBar is the view, and mySearchDisplayController only CONTROLS the
>   searchBar etc.

and also this:

> Just make your view controller implement the UISearchBarDelegate. In
>   your xib file, all you need to do is to add a UISearchBar to your view
>   and configure it as necessary, create an outlet for it (optional
>   really but helps to be explicit), and assign the delegate outlet to
>   your view controller. Then, to respond to the search bar events,
>   implement the UISearchBarDelegate protocol methods as necessary. For
>   example:
>   - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
>       [self handleSearch:searchBar]; }
>
> - (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
>     [self handleSearch:searchBar]; }
> - (void)handleSearch:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
>     NSLog(@"User searched for %@", searchBar.text);
>     [searchBar resignFirstResponder]; // if you want the keyboard to go away }
> - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *) searchBar {
>     NSLog(@"User canceled search");
>     [searchBar resignFirstResponder]; // if you want the keyboard to go away }

I'm just not getting it!  Should I be adding mySearchController to my UIView? or my UISearchBar?  Adding it to my UIView, nothing happens; adding it to my UISearchBar really wigs out the application.  I don't even get an error - it just hangs.

Then, there is the second part:  The delegate.  Should I put the delegate in my UIView?  Or in the UISearchDisplayController?  Not sure which direction to go in and nothing so far is working.  Please help.

All I really want at this point is just to get the handleSearch method to get executed.  Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Very confused.

Comment: Do you need a uisearchdisplaycontroller? Or do you just want a UISearchBar?

Comment: Not sure if I need a uisearchdisplaycontroller.  I have a uiviewcontroller and a uisearchbar in my xib.  I'm just trying to get a method to fire when user presses the search icon.  Thank you.

Comment: K. The UISearchDisplayController has it's own tableview that will show results. So when you press the searchbar with your finger it will show a cancel button, take up more of the screen, and show a blank tableview that says "no results". If you simply want a UISearchBar then just use a uisearchbar and watch for it's delegate method for when the search button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you create a Search Bar in Interface Builder as an outlet and then use the following code to create UISearchDisplayController:

```
self.searchDisplayController2 = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
self.searchDisplayController2.delegate = self;
self.searchDisplayController2.searchResultsDelegate = self;
self.searchDisplayController2.searchResultsDataSource = self;
```

This code would be implemented in your View Controller, say in `viewDidLoad`. You will also have to implement at least two delegate functions in the same VC:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```